# Why does tz_localize('CET') in pandas not behave as 'UTC+1'?

Tags: python, pandas

According to the [tz_localize documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html), CET equals UTC+1. Why does tz_localize('CET') in pandas not behave as 'UTC+1'?

```
import pandas as pd
tz_naive = pd.date_range('2020-03-29 00:00', periods=4, freq='H')
print(tz_naive)
```

results in:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00', '2020-03-29 01:00:00',
               '2020-03-29 02:00:00', '2020-03-29 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```

Since 'CET' = 'UTC+1' I would expect `tz_naive.tz_localize(tz='CET')` to result in:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-29 00:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-29 01:00:00+01:00',
               '2020-03-29 02:00:00+01:00', '2020-03-29 03:00:00+01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, CET]', freq='H')
```

...but it didn't. Instead it raises `NonExistentTimeError: 2020-03-29 02:00:00`. At '2020-03-29 02:00:00' we went from DST to non-DST. I thought CET is always UTC+1 but either I am wrong or tz_localize() does not behave accordingly. Who is able to (dis)confirm me?